# How to get the selected image from the list-box in windows phone?

Tags: image, listbox, windows-phone-8

```
I use the below code for add images into list box.

public class ImageData
    {
        public string ImagePath
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
private void Images_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
List<ImageData> dataSource = new List<ImageData>() 
                { 
                    new ImageData(){Name="XXX", ImagePath="XXX.png"},
                    new ImageData(){Name="YYY", ImagePath="YYY.png"},
                    new ImageData(){Name="ZZZ", ImagePath="ZZZ.png"},
                };

        this.Image_List.ItemsSource = dataSource;
}
```

This Code is working fine....

Now I want to select particular image and paste it into the image control or canvas.

It is possible.

Please Help Me.   Thanks In Advance........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use SelectedItem property and cast it to ImageData

```
var selectedImage = (ImageData)this.Image_List.SelectedItem;
```

there is good example of how to use it on msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged.aspx